# Add newline between the output

Tags: javascript, newline

I want to create a newline in the website, making the rows go under each other. I can add a space in the javascript code, but I cannot add a newline. I have tried "\n", "
" and more. The rows are still print out on the same row. How can I solve this? This is a snippet of the code:

```js
var txtElem = document.getElementById("text");

if (txtElem.textContent == "tomt") {
  // Första gången: sätt rubrik och text
  document.getElementById("rubrik").textContent = myArr['title'];
  //Ändrar hemsidans titel till titeln man skickar från serversidan i "Respons"
  txtElem.textContent = myArr['text'];
  for (i = 0; i < myArr['data'].length; i++) {
     txtElem.textContent += myArr['data'][i]["Nr"] + " " + myArr['data'][i]["Namn"] + " " + myArr['data'][i]["Telefonnummer"];
  }
}
```

```html
<p id="text">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s</p>
```

This last row is producing a line with the requested data, but between the "iterations", "laps" or what it's called I would like it to switch row. Right now it looks like this:

> Databas över hundar och dess ägare
> Tabell: 1 Alice 397062 Filip 456153 Humberto 432732

I would like there to be a break between "Alice", "Filip and "Humberto"

Comment: Use `<br>` HTML.

Answer (score 0):

use innerHTML instead of textContent.
div.innerHTML = "first line `<br>` second line";